# Disambiguate tag excerpts for [d-prime], [sensitivity] and [sensitivity-analysis]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms, tag-excerpt

It seemed like these tags might sometimes get confused, can the excerpts be improved?

- [d-prime](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d-prime) is [*sensitivity index*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_index) is a measure used in signal detection theory to quantify how well a signal can be distinguished from noise; hit rate and false-alarm rate
- [sensitivity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensitivity) or recall = true positive rate(TPR) = TP/(TP+FN) = TP/P is a performance metric of a binary classifier. Similarly specificity = TN/N = TN/(TN+FP)
- and there is of course also [sensitivity-analysis](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensitivity-analysis) ([Wiki excerpt for [sensitivity-analysis] tag?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5245/definition-for-sensitivity-analysis-tag))

Comment: How is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_index a synonym of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensitivity_and_specificity#Sensitivity ? It's two unrelated things.

Comment: But to prevent confusion, it might make sense to merge [sensitivity] and [specificity] into [sensitivity-specificity], like Wikipedia does.

Comment: @amoeba: Yes I'm stupid, I rewrote the question to just say how do we prevent them getting confused. Should you separately post your merge  suggestion on [sensitivity-specificity]?

Comment: I haven't seen any objections to my suggestions below, @smci. Let me know if you have any, or any further comments. Otherwise, I'll go ahead w/ those proposals.

Comment: @gung, sure, except we haven't reached final consensus on [tag:sensitivity-analysis] tag excerpt and definition

Comment: That's fair, @smci. I'll do the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose:

1. We create a new tag `[sensitivity-specificity]`, as @amoeba suggested.  We make the existing tags, [sensitivity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensitivity) and [specificity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specificity) synonyms of this and merge them.  (We will first need to ensure that the threats tagged with [sensitivity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sensitivity) are correct, of course.)  Note that we have a tag for [precision-recall](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/precision-recall), so combining has some precedent.
2. We create a tag for `[sensitivity-index]`, and make it a synonym of `[d-prime]`.
3. I think the excerpt for `[sensitivity-analysis]` is largely correct (cf., my answer here: [Wiki excerpt for [sensitivity-analysis] tag?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5249/7290)), but the excerpt could possibly be clarified.

Comment: +1. I edited d-prime excerpt and wiki to say "also called sensitivity index" instead of "also called sensitivity".

Comment: #1 & #2 have now been done.